# magento set dropdown attribute value by selected value instead of id

Tags: product, magento-1

i wrote custom code to assign attribute to product , issue is with dropdown attribute say color with values : red , green , yellow

not i want to set value of color to be red so i used code below

```
$product->setColor('red')
```

but it does not works as i neet to put id instead of vlaue , but i do not want to put id , can anyone help in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
  //Possible color value
  $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color'); //"color" is the attribute_code
  $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
  foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
    $value = $instance['label']; //Label of the option
  }
?>
```

it will display your **Label** and **ID**